# Necesito implementar en un textview que se muestre la hora y se vaya actualizando

Tags: java, android, hilos

Necesito implementar en un `Textview` que se muestre la hora y se vaya actualizando, la cosa es que me funciona pero se queda estática, y estoy trabajando con Android Studio y en `Fragment`. ojalá tener. esto es parte del código:

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        vista=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ingreso, container, false);

        txtHoraFecha=(TextView)vista.findViewById(R.id.txtFechaHora);

        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (!isInterrupted()) {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                long date = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
                                String dateString = sdf.format(date);
                                txtHoraFecha.setText(dateString);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Hola Sebastian, estas declarando correctamente el Thread, el TextView, debe encontrarse dentro de fragment_ingreso.xml  y solo necesitas iniciarlo usando el método start(), saludos.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas iniciar el Thread usando el método [**start()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start--):

```
thread.start();
```

Declara tu thread, e inicialo posteriormente:

```
  Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (!isInterrupted()) {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                long date = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
                                String dateString = sdf.format(date);
                                txtHoraFecha.setText(dateString);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        };

       thread.start();
```